# Mojo Routes: Handle asorted tags in url

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious, mojo

I am building a Mojo app to replace a vanilla mod_perl application.

The app currently handles url structures like:

```
/
/type/bold/
/keyword/hello/
/audience/all/
/type/bold/keyword/hello/
/keyword/hello/audience/all/
/keyword/hello/type/bold/audience/all/
/audience/all/type/bold/keyword/hello/
```

key/value pairs in the URL, that can exist in any order.

I am looking for a way to handle that without simply making a route for every permutation of tag, as that gets repetitive even after 3 different types of tags

Answer (score 1):

In that case you should probably just make a route that matches everything and parse the url yourself.